# Increase Column in Table Layout Android Studio

Tags: java, android, list, android-tablayout

I have Code Of Table Layout and I want to increase the table columns . I am new to the field of development and android table layout...
I want to Increase the no of columns in the Table as I am using the android table layout!!

But I am still confused how to do!!

Here is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/invoices_layout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableInvoices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:stretchColumns="*">
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is my Main Activity Java File

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TableLayout mTableLayout;
ProgressDialog mProgressBar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mProgressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableInvoices);
    mTableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    startLoadData();
}
public void startLoadData() {
    mProgressBar.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressBar.setMessage("Fetching Invoices..");
    mProgressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    mProgressBar.show();
    new LoadDataTask().execute(0);
}
public void loadData() {
    int leftRowMargin=0;
    int topRowMargin=0;
    int rightRowMargin=0;
    int bottomRowMargin = 0;
    int textSize = 0, smallTextSize = 0 , mediumTextSize = 0;
    textSize = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size_verysmall);
    smallTextSize = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size_small);
    mediumTextSize = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size_medium);
    Invoices invoices = new Invoices();
    InvoiceData[] data = invoices.getInvoices();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy");
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    int rows = data.length;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Invoices (" + String.valueOf(rows) + ")");

    TextView textSpacer = null;
    mTableLayout.removeAllViews();
            for(int i = -1; i < rows; i ++) {
        InvoiceData row = null;
        if (i > -1)
        row = data[i];
        else {
            textSpacer = new TextView(this);
            textSpacer.setText("");
        }
        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        tv.setPadding(5, 15, 0, 15);

        if (i == -1) {
            tv.setText("Inv.#");
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, smallTextSize);
        } else {
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(row.invoiceNumber));
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
        }

        final TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        if (i == -1) {
            tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, smallTextSize);
        } else {
            tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            tv2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
        }

        tv2.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        tv2.setPadding(5, 15, 0, 15);
        if (i == -1) {
            tv2.setText("Date");
            tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f7"));
        }else {
            tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            tv2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            tv2.setText(dateFormat.format(row.invoiceDate));
        }
        final LinearLayout layCustomer = new LinearLayout(this);
        layCustomer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layCustomer.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
        layCustomer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));
        final TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
        if (i == -1) {
            tv3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            tv3.setPadding(5, 5, 0, 5);
            tv3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, smallTextSize);
        } else {
            tv3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            tv3.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 5);
            tv3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
        }
        tv3.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
        if (i == -1) {
            tv3.setText("Customer");
            tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));
        } else {

            tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));
            tv3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            tv3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, smallTextSize);
            tv3.setText(row.customerName);
        }

        layCustomer.addView(tv3);
        if (i > -1) {
            final TextView tv3b = new TextView(this);
            tv3b.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv3b.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            tv3b.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
            tv3b.setPadding(5, 1, 0, 5);
            tv3b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#aaaaaa"));
            tv3b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));
            tv3b.setText(row.customerAddress);
            layCustomer.addView(tv3b);
        }

        final LinearLayout layAmounts = new LinearLayout(this);
        layAmounts.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layAmounts.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        layAmounts.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
        layAmounts.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        final TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
        if (i == -1) {
            tv4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            tv4.setPadding(5, 5, 1, 5);
            layAmounts.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f7"));
        } else {
            tv4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv4.setPadding(5, 0, 1, 5);
            layAmounts.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
        tv4.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        if (i == -1) {
            tv4.setText("Inv.Amount");
            tv4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f7"));
            tv4.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, smallTextSize);
        } else {
            tv4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            tv4.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            tv4.setText(decimalFormat.format(row.invoiceAmount));
            tv4.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
        }
        layAmounts.addView(tv4);
        if (i > -1) {
            final TextView tv4b = new TextView(this);
            tv4b.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv4b.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            tv4b.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
            tv4b.setPadding(2, 2, 1, 5);
            tv4b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00afff"));
            tv4b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            String due = "";
            if (row.amountDue.compareTo(new BigDecimal(0.01)) == 1) {
                due = "Due:" + decimalFormat.format(row.amountDue);
                due = due.trim();
            }
            tv4b.setText(due);
            layAmounts.addView(tv4b);
        }
        // add table row
        final TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setId(i + 1);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams trParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        trParams.setMargins(leftRowMargin, topRowMargin, rightRowMargin, bottomRowMargin);
        tr.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        tr.setLayoutParams(trParams);
        tr.addView(tv);
        tr.addView(tv2);
        tr.addView(layCustomer);
        tr.addView(layAmounts);

        if (i > -1) {
            tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TableRow tr = (TableRow) v;

                }
            });
        }
        mTableLayout.addView(tr, trParams);
        if (i > -1) {
            // add separator row
            final TableRow trSep = new TableRow(this);
            TableLayout.LayoutParams trParamsSep = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            trParamsSep.setMargins(leftRowMargin, topRowMargin, rightRowMargin, bottomRowMargin);
            trSep.setLayoutParams(trParamsSep);
            TextView tvSep = new TextView(this);

            TableRow.LayoutParams tvSepLay = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tvSepLay.span = 4;
            tvSep.setLayoutParams(tvSepLay);

            tvSep.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d9d9d9"));
            tvSep.setHeight(1);
            trSep.addView(tvSep);
            mTableLayout.addView(trSep, trParamsSep);

        }
    }
}


 class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "Task Completed.";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mProgressBar.hide();
            loadData();
                 }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        }
    }

}
```

Here is My Model Class

```
    public class InvoiceData {

    public int id;
    public int invoiceNumber;
    public Date invoiceDate;
    public String customerName;
    public String customerAddress;
    public BigDecimal invoiceAmount;
    public BigDecimal amountDue;

}
```

Here is my Invoices Class

```
 public class Invoices {

    public InvoiceData[] getInvoices() {
        InvoiceData[] data = new InvoiceData[20];
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
            InvoiceData row = new InvoiceData();
            row.id = (i+1);
            row.invoiceNumber = row.id;
            row.amountDue = BigDecimal.valueOf(20.00 * i);
            row.invoiceAmount = BigDecimal.valueOf(120.00 * (i+1));
            row.invoiceDate = new Date();
            row.customerName =  "Thomas John Beckett";
            row.customerAddress = "1112, Hash Avenue, NYC";
            //row.Code= "1233";
            data[i] = row;
        }
        return data;
    }

}
```

What I want to do is I want to Increase No of Columns in the Table...

adding more columns not showing Small screen

[image]

I have 8 columns But It only showing 6

Answer (score 1):

You can review [Blackie answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50560927/10222681) here to know how to implement the number of columns in the TableLayout using xml.
For your example you can use it in something like this:

```
        <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableInvoices"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:stretchColumns="7">
        <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1" />
               <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1" />
              <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1" />
              <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1" />

        </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

For the small horizontal  size you have a number of solutions:

1- Using smaller textSize for titles and all other textViews and using `wrap_content`.
2- Using LinearLayout instead of TableLayout, and give layout_weight per column.
3- Using horizontal ScrollView.

Comment: And i Want to get Sqlite data I have in my Database Class

Comment: For data in Sqlite database you need to create a database helper class, and after that you will also need an Adapter for your recyclerview (to display them), you can find a full tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RBnC2mMY8U

Comment: After Adding more columns The Other Items not showing

Comment: I think this tutorial might not help me because I want TableView and I have Columns in the table

Comment: This man is using the list view and recycler view to get his desired result

Comment: What other items? you can make it wrap_content to only take the space it needs. In your case you will only need to change the adapter item to be this tablelayout, all others are the same, but sure it is not easy as expected, it only needs some practice.

Comment: I have 18 Columns I want to show in my Table and over 50Rows....

There is no problem with row I scrolling down to see them but After adding ,more columns It is not showing perfectly....

Comment: WHen I add more columns the complete colums not showing

Comment: I have 18 columns in the table the screen is only capable to show 6  or 7 columns, Is there any way to show All items on a screen or Any chance of scrolling like vertical scrolling... If yes then How?

Comment: @AliceAlex you can if you make the textsize very small and this is not a good practice, I can suggest you to display few columns with a popup (dialog) when clicking on a row with the other data, This is the best practice for smartphones.

Comment: If I use Horizontal scroll view then vertical scroll view not working